Trying to redirect using api
here I am trying to use a api to redirect to another url if a particular condition passes.In the first case if profile is already complete then it will redirect to home page if not then it must redirect me to profile completion page.Is there any changes in code I used do to achieve this
I tried this code and applied the logic but in postman I'm unable to test this. How to solve this issue

Please edit your question to include a reproducible example rather than an image of your code.

Create a test!

The only cogent reason to perform a redirect on a user request to a REST API is when there is a URL change. If you were sending HTML, a redirect from one view to another will also be reasonable. Nonetheless, the choice of a user to follow a redirect is still up to the user. Some browsers enforce this whereas others always ask users if they want to follow the redirect. If you are okay with this response, I will write an answer that goes into detail on both server side using DRF and client side using the browser’s fetch API.
